# Custom Model for Odoo Authentication

Tags: authentication, module, odoo

Please help me with my current problem.

I want to build an application that involves 2 different users namely, student and teacher. Each user should be able to log into the application.

I wanted to use the student and teacher models where username and password are stored for the authentication.

Currently, I don't know how to configure Odoo to look for the mentioned models for the authentication. I can't find any tutorials that could help me accomplish this even in the Odoo documentation.

Please help how to do this or provide advice if there is a better way of doing this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please refer link for create module in odoo (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html)

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? There already is this feature in Odoo.